# button type='submit' with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

Which function, `submit` or `onClick` will run first? Or will they run simultaneously?

In my program `onClick` function runs first and then `onSubmit`. But why and is it always like that?

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Field>
        <label>Enter new password:</label>
        <input 
            type="text"
            name= 'newPassword'
            onChange={handleOnChange} 
            placeholder='New Password' 
            required
            />
    </Form.Field>
    <Button type='submit' onClick={handleClick}>Submit</Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: Think of it like a tree. When you click the button, the onclick in the button is the stump of the tree, and it gets run first. Then it starts going outwards, and further up the tree, the trunk is onsubmit, and then it runs. That's why onclick gets ran first.

Comment: I mean after clicking, the form is submitted. Isn't it logical to have click event fire first seeing as click is the former event that triggers the latter event-submit?

Comment: @TheMaster seems logical thanks

Comment: I have one more question: Will the functions fire one AFTER another or there may be a situation where handleOnClick function finishes after handleOnSubmit?

Comment: Try running a long loop inside `handleClick` and `return false;` at the end. Also read about `event.preventDefault()` PS: You need to use `@` to notify us. You should also ask new questions in a new post.

Comment: Reformatted code for easier readability

Answer (score 0):

If you are using formik you can pass handleSubmit to your button onClick and use your code and logics in the callback onSubmit

```
<Form onSubmit={(values) => yourHandleSubmitMethod(values)}>
    <Form.Field>
        <label>Enter new password:</label>
        <input 
            type="text"
            name= 'newPassword'
            onChange={handleOnChange} 
            placeholder='New Password' 
            required
            />
    </Form.Field>
    <Button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
</Form>
```